# Inequality involving $x^4=(z+y^2)(z-y^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality

If
$$x^4=(z+y^2)(z-y^2),$$
$$z+y^2=2u^4,$$
$$z-y^2=8v^4,$$
$$(u^2+y)(u^2-y)=4v^2,$$
$$u^2+y=2r^4,$$
$$u^2-y=2s^4,$$
$$r^4+s^4=u^2,$$
then show that $r\lt x$ and $s\lt x$ (where $x,y,z,u,v,r,s$ are positive integers). This is intended to prove a special case of Fermat's last theorem by contradiction.

**My attempt:**

**First part**
$$4u^8=(z+y^2)(z+y^2)\gt x^4=16u^4 v^4$$
$$u^4\gt 16v^4\gt v^4$$
$$u\gt v$$
**Second part**
$$(u^2+y)(u^2-y)\lt 4u^2$$
$$u^4-y^2\lt 4u^2$$
$$y^2\gt u^4-4u^2$$
**Third part**
$$y^4\lt z^2\implies y^2\lt z$$
$$z\gt u^4-4u^2$$
$$2s^4\lt u^2\implies 4s^8\lt u^4$$
So I concluded that
$$z\gt 4s^8-8s^4.$$
But I don't know what should I do next.

Answer (score 1):

If $z+y^2=2u^4$, then $r^4+s^4=u^2\lt z+y^2$. But we also have
$$z+y^2\lt (z+y^2)(z-y^2)=x^4,$$
so $r^4+s^4\lt x^4\implies r,s\lt x$.